# Unable to import gurobipy to python but installed correctly

Tags: python

On my Windows 10 system, Gurobi is installed correctly, license installed and the environmental variable set up as in the [quick start guide](https://www.gurobi.com/wp-content/plugins/hd_documentations/content/pdf/quickstart_windows_8.1.pdf). The following cmd transcript sums it up quite nicely.

## Everything seems to be in order ...

```
C:\Users\User1>gurobi
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:08:48) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Academic license - for non-commercial use only

Gurobi Interactive Shell (win64), Version 8.0.0
Copyright (c) 2018, Gurobi Optimization, LLC
Type "help()" for help

gurobi>
```

## However ...

```
C:\Users\User1>python
Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gurobipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named gurobipy
```

Why is this happening and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this happening and how can I resolve it?

You apparently have two separate versions of Python 2.x installed on your system (`Python 2.7.8` and `Python 2.7.15`). Each of these installations is treated separately. You seem to have Gurobi associated with `Python 2.7.8` (not `Python 2.7.15`).

Reading through the documentation you linked, Gurobi comes with an interpreter (`Python 2.7.8` I am assuming). However, you need to install  the Gurobi Python interface in your command line version of Python (e.g. `Python 2.7.15`).

Based on the official Gurobi documentation, it seems Gurobi may have the necessary setup files for this interface in its installation directory somewhere. You will need to look for `setup.py`, open a command window in that same directory and then run `python setup.py install` from the command line in order to install the interface correctly.

[As a small note, the latest version of Python 2.x is Python 2.7.16](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).

Comment: this works perfectly!

Comment: Glad it helped. =)